# Grid Template Columns not working on media queries

Tags: html, css, media-queries, css-grid

I don't know why:

```
grid-template-columns: 1fr;
```

isn't working for:

```
@media (max-width: 376px)
```

My code:

```css
*,
*::before,
*::after {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

html {
  font-size: 62.5%;
}

body {
  font-family: "Spartan", sans-serif;
  font-weight: 400;
  font-size: 1.5rem;
  line-height: 1;
  color: hsl(303, 10%, 53%);
}

main {
  min-height: 100vh;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;

  background-image: url(images/bg-pattern-top-desktop.svg),
    url(images/bg-pattern-bottom-desktop.svg);
  background-position: top left, bottom right;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  padding: 2.4rem;
}

.card {
  max-width: 120rem;
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: 1fr 1fr;
  column-gap: 22rem;
  row-gap: 6.4rem;
}

.heading {
  font-size: 4.4rem;
  color: hsl(300, 43%, 22%);
  line-height: 1.2;
  font-weight: 700;
  margin-bottom: 2.4rem;
}

.sub-heading {
  line-height: 1.7;
  font-weight: 500;
}

.ratings {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  gap: 1.8rem;
  margin: 2.4rem 0;
}

.rating {
  background-color: hsl(300, 24%, 96%);
  padding: 1.8rem 2.4rem;
  border-radius: 8px;
  color: hsl(300, 43%, 22%);
  font-weight: 700;
}

.rating--reviews {
  transform: translateX(-7.2rem);
}

.rating--guru {
  transform: translateX(-3.6rem);
}

.icons {
  margin-right: 2.4rem;
}

.testimonials {
  grid-column: span 2;
  display: flex;
  gap: 2.4rem;
}

.testimonial {
  background-color: hsl(300, 43%, 22%);
  padding: 4.8rem 2.4rem;
  border-radius: 9px;
}

.testimonial-irene {
  transform: translateY(2.4rem);
}

.testimonial-anne {
  transform: translateY(4.8rem);
}

.user-details {
  display: flex;
  gap: 1.6rem;
  align-items: center;
  margin-bottom: 2.4rem;
}

.testimonial-img {
  width: 4rem;
  border-radius: 50%;
}

.user-content {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  gap: 0.6rem;
  align-items: center;
}

.user-name {
  font-size: 1.4rem;
  color: hsl(0, 0%, 100%);
  font-weight: 700;
}

.user-verified {
  color: hsl(333, 80%, 67%);
  font-size: 1.4rem;
  font-weight: 500;
}

.testimonial blockquote {
  line-height: 1.6;
  font-weight: 500;
  color: hsl(300, 24%, 96%);
}

@media (max-width: 376px) {
  main {
    background-image: url(images/bg-pattern-top-mobile.svg),
      url(images/bg-pattern-bottom-mobile.svg);
  }

  .card {
    grid-template-columns: 1fr;
    gap: 0;
  }
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
    <!-- displays site properly based on user's device -->

    <link
      rel="icon"
      type="image/png"
      sizes="32x32"
      href="./images/favicon-32x32.png"
    />
    <link rel="preconnect" href="https://fonts.googleapis.com" />
    <link rel="preconnect" href="https://fonts.gstatic.com" crossorigin />
    <link
      href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Spartan:wght@400;500;700&display=swap"
      rel="stylesheet"
    />
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css" />

    <title>Frontend Mentor | Social proof section</title>
  </head>
  <body>
    <main>
      <section class="card">
        <div class="card--text-content">
          <h1 class="heading">10,000+ of our users love our products.</h1>
          <p class="sub-heading">
            We only provide great products combined with excellent customer
            service. See what our satisfied customers are saying about our
            services.
          </p>
        </div>
        <div class="ratings">
          <p class="rating rating--reviews">
            <span class="icons">
              <svg
                class="icon"
                width="17"
                height="16"
                xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"
              >
                <path
                  d="M16.539 6.097a.297.297 0 00-.24-.202l-5.36-.779L8.542.26a.296.296 0 00-.53 0L5.613 5.117l-5.36.779a.297.297 0 00-.165.505l3.88 3.78-.917 5.34a.297.297 0 00.43.312l4.795-2.52 4.794 2.52a.296.296 0 00.43-.313l-.916-5.338L16.464 6.4c.08-.08.11-.197.075-.304z"
                  fill="#EF9546"
                  fill-rule="nonzero"
                />
              </svg>
              <svg
                class="icon"
                width="17"
                height="16"
                xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"
              >
                <path
                  d="M16.539 6.097a.297.297 0 00-.24-.202l-5.36-.779L8.542.26a.296.296 0 00-.53 0L5.613 5.117l-5.36.779a.297.297 0 00-.165.505l3.88 3.78-.917 5.34a.297.297 0 00.43.312l4.795-2.52 4.794 2.52a.296.296 0 00.43-.313l-.916-5.338L16.464 6.4c.08-.08.11-.197.075-.304z"
                  fill="#EF9546"
                  fill-rule="nonzero"
                />
              </svg>
              <svg
                class="icon"
                width="17"
                height="16"
                xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"
              >
                <path
                  d="M16.539 6.097a.297.297 0 00-.24-.202l-5.36-.779L8.542.26a.296.296 0 00-.53 0L5.613 5.117l-5.36.779a.297.297 0 00-.165.505l3.88 3.78-.917 5.34a.297.297 0 00.43.312l4.795-2.52 4.794 2.52a.296.296 0 00.43-.313l-.916-5.338L16.464 6.4c.08-.08.11-.197.075-.304z"
                  fill="#EF9546"
                  fill-rule="nonzero"
                />
              </svg>
              <svg
                class="icon"
                width="17"
                height="16"
                xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"
              >
                <path
                  d="M16.539 6.097a.297.297 0 00-.24-.202l-5.36-.779L8.542.26a.296.296 0 00-.53 0L5.613 5.117l-5.36.779a.297.297 0 00-.165.505l3.88 3.78-.917 5.34a.297.297 0 00.43.312l4.795-2.52 4.794 2.52a.296.296 0 00.43-.313l-.916-5.338L16.464 6.4c.08-.08.11-.197.075-.304z"
                  fill="#EF9546"
                  fill-rule="nonzero"
                />
              </svg>
              <svg
                class="icon"
                width="17"
                height="16"
                xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"
              >
                <path
                  d="M16.539 6.097a.297.297 0 00-.24-.202l-5.36-.779L8.542.26a.296.296 0 00-.53 0L5.613 5.117l-5.36.779a.297.297 0 00-.165.505l3.88 3.78-.917 5.34a.297.297 0 00.43.312l4.795-2.52 4.794 2.52a.296.296 0 00.43-.313l-.916-5.338L16.464 6.4c.08-.08.11-.197.075-.304z"
                  fill="#EF9546"
                  fill-rule="nonzero"
                />
              </svg>
            </span>
            Rated 5 Stars in Reviews
          </p>
          <p class="rating rating--guru">
            <span class="icons">
              <svg
                class="icon"
                width="17"
                height="16"
                xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"
              >
                <path
                  d="M16.539 6.097a.297.297 0 00-.24-.202l-5.36-.779L8.542.26a.296.296 0 00-.53 0L5.613 5.117l-5.36.779a.297.297 0 00-.165.505l3.88 3.78-.917 5.34a.297.297 0 00.43.312l4.795-2.52 4.794 2.52a.296.296 0 00.43-.313l-.916-5.338L16.464 6.4c.08-.08.11-.197.075-.304z"
                  fill="#EF9546"
                  fill-rule="nonzero"
                />
              </svg>
              <svg
                class="icon"
                width="17"
                height="16"
                xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"
              >
                <path
                  d="M16.539 6.097a.297.297 0 00-.24-.202l-5.36-.779L8.542.26a.296.296 0 00-.53 0L5.613 5.117l-5.36.779a.297.297 0 00-.165.505l3.88 3.78-.917 5.34a.297.297 0 00.43.312l4.795-2.52 4.794 2.52a.296.296 0 00.43-.313l-.916-5.338L16.464 6.4c.08-.08.11-.197.075-.304z"
                  fill="#EF9546"
                  fill-rule="nonzero"
                />
              </svg>
              <svg
                class="icon"
                width="17"
                height="16"
                xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"
              >
                <path
                  d="M16.539 6.097a.297.297 0 00-.24-.202l-5.36-.779L8.542.26a.296.296 0 00-.53 0L5.613 5.117l-5.36.779a.297.297 0 00-.165.505l3.88 3.78-.917 5.34a.297.297 0 00.43.312l4.795-2.52 4.794 2.52a.296.296 0 00.43-.313l-.916-5.338L16.464 6.4c.08-.08.11-.197.075-.304z"
                  fill="#EF9546"
                  fill-rule="nonzero"
                />
              </svg>
              <svg
                class="icon"
                width="17"
                height="16"
                xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"
              >
                <path
                  d="M16.539 6.097a.297.297 0 00-.24-.202l-5.36-.779L8.542.26a.296.296 0 00-.53 0L5.613 5.117l-5.36.779a.297.297 0 00-.165.505l3.88 3.78-.917 5.34a.297.297 0 00.43.312l4.795-2.52 4.794 2.52a.296.296 0 00.43-.313l-.916-5.338L16.464 6.4c.08-.08.11-.197.075-.304z"
                  fill="#EF9546"
                  fill-rule="nonzero"
                />
              </svg>
              <svg
                class="icon"
                width="17"
                height="16"
                xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"
              >
                <path
                  d="M16.539 6.097a.297.297 0 00-.24-.202l-5.36-.779L8.542.26a.296.296 0 00-.53 0L5.613 5.117l-5.36.779a.297.297 0 00-.165.505l3.88 3.78-.917 5.34a.297.297 0 00.43.312l4.795-2.52 4.794 2.52a.296.296 0 00.43-.313l-.916-5.338L16.464 6.4c.08-.08.11-.197.075-.304z"
                  fill="#EF9546"
                  fill-rule="nonzero"
                />
              </svg>
            </span>
            Rated 5 Stars in Report Guru
          </p>
          <p class="rating rating--best">
            <span class="icons">
              <svg
                class="icon"
                width="17"
                height="16"
                xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"
              >
                <path
                  d="M16.539 6.097a.297.297 0 00-.24-.202l-5.36-.779L8.542.26a.296.296 0 00-.53 0L5.613 5.117l-5.36.779a.297.297 0 00-.165.505l3.88 3.78-.917 5.34a.297.297 0 00.43.312l4.795-2.52 4.794 2.52a.296.296 0 00.43-.313l-.916-5.338L16.464 6.4c.08-.08.11-.197.075-.304z"
                  fill="#EF9546"
                  fill-rule="nonzero"
                />
              </svg>
              <svg
                class="icon"
                width="17"
                height="16"
                xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"
              >
                <path
                  d="M16.539 6.097a.297.297 0 00-.24-.202l-5.36-.779L8.542.26a.296.296 0 00-.53 0L5.613 5.117l-5.36.779a.297.297 0 00-.165.505l3.88 3.78-.917 5.34a.297.297 0 00.43.312l4.795-2.52 4.794 2.52a.296.296 0 00.43-.313l-.916-5.338L16.464 6.4c.08-.08.11-.197.075-.304z"
                  fill="#EF9546"
                  fill-rule="nonzero"
                />
              </svg>
              <svg
                class="icon"
                width="17"
                height="16"
                xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"
              >
                <path
                  d="M16.539 6.097a.297.297 0 00-.24-.202l-5.36-.779L8.542.26a.296.296 0 00-.53 0L5.613 5.117l-5.36.779a.297.297 0 00-.165.505l3.88 3.78-.917 5.34a.297.297 0 00.43.312l4.795-2.52 4.794 2.52a.296.296 0 00.43-.313l-.916-5.338L16.464 6.4c.08-.08.11-.197.075-.304z"
                  fill="#EF9546"
                  fill-rule="nonzero"
                />
              </svg>
              <svg
                class="icon"
                width="17"
                height="16"
                xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"
              >
                <path
                  d="M16.539 6.097a.297.297 0 00-.24-.202l-5.36-.779L8.542.26a.296.296 0 00-.53 0L5.613 5.117l-5.36.779a.297.297 0 00-.165.505l3.88 3.78-.917 5.34a.297.297 0 00.43.312l4.795-2.52 4.794 2.52a.296.296 0 00.43-.313l-.916-5.338L16.464 6.4c.08-.08.11-.197.075-.304z"
                  fill="#EF9546"
                  fill-rule="nonzero"
                />
              </svg>
              <svg
                class="icon"
                width="17"
                height="16"
                xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"
              >
                <path
                  d="M16.539 6.097a.297.297 0 00-.24-.202l-5.36-.779L8.542.26a.296.296 0 00-.53 0L5.613 5.117l-5.36.779a.297.297 0 00-.165.505l3.88 3.78-.917 5.34a.297.297 0 00.43.312l4.795-2.52 4.794 2.52a.296.296 0 00.43-.313l-.916-5.338L16.464 6.4c.08-.08.11-.197.075-.304z"
                  fill="#EF9546"
                  fill-rule="nonzero"
                />
              </svg>
            </span>
            Rated 5 Stars in BestTech
          </p>
        </div>
        <div class="testimonials">
          <figure class="testimonial testimonial-colton">
            <div class="user-details">
              <img
                src="images/image-colton.jpg"
                class="testimonial-img"
                alt="Image of User"
              />
              <div class="user-content">
                <p class="user-name">Colton Smith</p>
                <p class="user-verified">Verified Buyer</p>
              </div>
            </div>
            <blockquote>
              "We needed the same printed design as the one we had ordered a
              week prior. Not only did they find the original order, but we also
              received it in time. Excellent!"
            </blockquote>
          </figure>
          <figure class="testimonial testimonial-irene">
            <div class="user-details">
              <img
                src="images/image-irene.jpg"
                class="testimonial-img"
                alt="Image of User"
              />
              <div class="user-content">
                <p class="user-name">Irene Roberts</p>
                <p class="user-verified">Verified Buyer</p>
              </div>
            </div>
            <blockquote>
              "Customer service is always excellent and very quick turn around.
              Completely delighted with the simplicity of the purchase and the
              speed of delivery."
            </blockquote>
          </figure>
          <figure class="testimonial testimonial-anne">
            <div class="user-details">
              <img
                src="images/image-anne.jpg"
                class="testimonial-img"
                alt="Image of User"
              />
              <div class="user-content">
                <p class="user-name">Anne Wallace</p>
                <p class="user-verified">Verified Buyer</p>
              </div>
            </div>
            <blockquote>
              "Put an order with this company and can only praise them for the
              very high standard. Will definitely use them again and recommend
              them to everyone!"
            </blockquote>
          </figure>
        </div>
      </section>
    </main>
  </body>
</html>
```

[Code and result side by side](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lpbG1.png)

Answer (score 0):

The problem is using translateX with pixels - 1 rem = 16 px; This is what makes your grid elements cover the text on the right

```css
*,
*::before,
*::after {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

html {
  font-size: 62.5%;
}

body {
  font-family: "Spartan", sans-serif;
  font-weight: 400;
  font-size: 1.5rem;
  line-height: 1;
  color: hsl(303, 10%, 53%);
}

main {
  min-height: 100vh;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;

  background-image: url(images/bg-pattern-top-desktop.svg),
    url(images/bg-pattern-bottom-desktop.svg);
  background-position: top left, bottom right;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  padding: 2.4rem;
}

.card {
  max-width: 120rem;
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: 1fr 1fr;
  column-gap: 22rem;
  row-gap: 6.4rem;
}

.heading {
  font-size: 4.4rem;
  color: hsl(300, 43%, 22%);
  line-height: 1.2;
  font-weight: 700;
  margin-bottom: 2.4rem;
}

.sub-heading {
  line-height: 1.7;
  font-weight: 500;
}

.ratings {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  gap: 1.8rem;
  margin: 2.4rem 0;
}

.rating {
  background-color: hsl(300, 24%, 96%);
  padding: 1.8rem 2.4rem;
  border-radius: 8px;
  color: hsl(300, 43%, 22%);
  font-weight: 700;
}

.rating--reviews {
  transform: translateX(-7.2%);
}

.rating--guru {
  transform: translateX(-3.6%);
}

.icons {
  margin-right: 2.4rem;
}

.testimonials {
  grid-column: span 2;
  display: flex;
  gap: 2.4rem;
}

.testimonial {
  background-color: hsl(300, 43%, 22%);
  padding: 4.8rem 2.4rem;
  border-radius: 9px;
}

.testimonial-irene {
  transform: translateY(2.4rem);
}

.testimonial-anne {
  transform: translateY(4.8rem);
}

.user-details {
  display: flex;
  gap: 1.6rem;
  align-items: center;
  margin-bottom: 2.4rem;
}

.testimonial-img {
  width: 4rem;
  border-radius: 50%;
}

.user-content {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  gap: 0.6rem;
  align-items: center;
}

.user-name {
  font-size: 1.4rem;
  color: hsl(0, 0%, 100%);
  font-weight: 700;
}

.user-verified {
  color: hsl(333, 80%, 67%);
  font-size: 1.4rem;
  font-weight: 500;
}

.testimonial blockquote {
  line-height: 1.6;
  font-weight: 500;
  color: hsl(300, 24%, 96%);
}

@media (max-width: 376px) {
  main {
    background-image: url(images/bg-pattern-top-mobile.svg),
      url(images/bg-pattern-bottom-mobile.svg);
  }
   
  .card {
    grid-template-columns: 1fr;
    gap: 0;
  }
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
    <!-- displays site properly based on user's device -->

    <link
      rel="icon"
      type="image/png"
      sizes="32x32"
      href="./images/favicon-32x32.png"
    />
    <link rel="preconnect" href="https://fonts.googleapis.com" />
    <link rel="preconnect" href="https://fonts.gstatic.com" crossorigin />
    <link
      href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Spartan:wght@400;500;700&display=swap"
      rel="stylesheet"
    />
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css" />

    <title>Frontend Mentor | Social proof section</title>
  </head>
  <body>
    <main>
      <section class="card">
        <div class="card--text-content">
          <h1 class="heading">10,000+ of our users love our products.</h1>
          <p class="sub-heading">
            We only provide great products combined with excellent customer
            service. See what our satisfied customers are saying about our
            services.
          </p>
        </div>
        <div class="ratings">
          <p class="rating rating--reviews">
            <span class="icons">
              <svg
                class="icon"
                width="17"
                height="16"
                xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"
              >
                <path
                  d="M16.539 6.097a.297.297 0 00-.24-.202l-5.36-.779L8.542.26a.296.296 0 00-.53 0L5.613 5.117l-5.36.779a.297.297 0 00-.165.505l3.88 3.78-.917 5.34a.297.297 0 00.43.312l4.795-2.52 4.794 2.52a.296.296 0 00.43-.313l-.916-5.338L16.464 6.4c.08-.08.11-.197.075-.304z"
                  fill="#EF9546"
                  fill-rule="nonzero"
                />
              </svg>
              <svg
                class="icon"
                width="17"
                height="16"
                xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"
              >
                <path
                  d="M16.539 6.097a.297.297 0 00-.24-.202l-5.36-.779L8.542.26a.296.296 0 00-.53 0L5.613 5.117l-5.36.779a.297.297 0 00-.165.505l3.88 3.78-.917 5.34a.297.297 0 00.43.312l4.795-2.52 4.794 2.52a.296.296 0 00.43-.313l-.916-5.338L16.464 6.4c.08-.08.11-.197.075-.304z"
                  fill="#EF9546"
                  fill-rule="nonzero"
                />
              </svg>
              <svg
                class="icon"
                width="17"
                height="16"
                xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"
              >
                <path
                  d="M16.539 6.097a.297.297 0 00-.24-.202l-5.36-.779L8.542.26a.296.296 0 00-.53 0L5.613 5.117l-5.36.779a.297.297 0 00-.165.505l3.88 3.78-.917 5.34a.297.297 0 00.43.312l4.795-2.52 4.794 2.52a.296.296 0 00.43-.313l-.916-5.338L16.464 6.4c.08-.08.11-.197.075-.304z"
                  fill="#EF9546"
                  fill-rule="nonzero"
                />
              </svg>
              <svg
                class="icon"
                width="17"
                height="16"
                xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"
              >
                <path
                  d="M16.539 6.097a.297.297 0 00-.24-.202l-5.36-.779L8.542.26a.296.296 0 00-.53 0L5.613 5.117l-5.36.779a.297.297 0 00-.165.505l3.88 3.78-.917 5.34a.297.297 0 00.43.312l4.795-2.52 4.794 2.52a.296.296 0 00.43-.313l-.916-5.338L16.464 6.4c.08-.08.11-.197.075-.304z"
                  fill="#EF9546"
                  fill-rule="nonzero"
                />
              </svg>
              <svg
                class="icon"
                width="17"
                height="16"
                xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"
              >
                <path
                  d="M16.539 6.097a.297.297 0 00-.24-.202l-5.36-.779L8.542.26a.296.296 0 00-.53 0L5.613 5.117l-5.36.779a.297.297 0 00-.165.505l3.88 3.78-.917 5.34a.297.297 0 00.43.312l4.795-2.52 4.794 2.52a.296.296 0 00.43-.313l-.916-5.338L16.464 6.4c.08-.08.11-.197.075-.304z"
                  fill="#EF9546"
                  fill-rule="nonzero"
                />
              </svg>
            </span>
            Rated 5 Stars in Reviews
          </p>
          <p class="rating rating--guru">
            <span class="icons">
              <svg
                class="icon"
                width="17"
                height="16"
                xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"
              >
                <path
                  d="M16.539 6.097a.297.297 0 00-.24-.202l-5.36-.779L8.542.26a.296.296 0 00-.53 0L5.613 5.117l-5.36.779a.297.297 0 00-.165.505l3.88 3.78-.917 5.34a.297.297 0 00.43.312l4.795-2.52 4.794 2.52a.296.296 0 00.43-.313l-.916-5.338L16.464 6.4c.08-.08.11-.197.075-.304z"
                  fill="#EF9546"
                  fill-rule="nonzero"
                />
              </svg>
              <svg
                class="icon"
                width="17"
                height="16"
                xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"
              >
                <path
                  d="M16.539 6.097a.297.297 0 00-.24-.202l-5.36-.779L8.542.26a.296.296 0 00-.53 0L5.613 5.117l-5.36.779a.297.297 0 00-.165.505l3.88 3.78-.917 5.34a.297.297 0 00.43.312l4.795-2.52 4.794 2.52a.296.296 0 00.43-.313l-.916-5.338L16.464 6.4c.08-.08.11-.197.075-.304z"
                  fill="#EF9546"
                  fill-rule="nonzero"
                />
              </svg>
              <svg
                class="icon"
                width="17"
                height="16"
                xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"
              >
                <path
                  d="M16.539 6.097a.297.297 0 00-.24-.202l-5.36-.779L8.542.26a.296.296 0 00-.53 0L5.613 5.117l-5.36.779a.297.297 0 00-.165.505l3.88 3.78-.917 5.34a.297.297 0 00.43.312l4.795-2.52 4.794 2.52a.296.296 0 00.43-.313l-.916-5.338L16.464 6.4c.08-.08.11-.197.075-.304z"
                  fill="#EF9546"
                  fill-rule="nonzero"
                />
              </svg>
              <svg
                class="icon"
                width="17"
                height="16"
                xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"
              >
                <path
                  d="M16.539 6.097a.297.297 0 00-.24-.202l-5.36-.779L8.542.26a.296.296 0 00-.53 0L5.613 5.117l-5.36.779a.297.297 0 00-.165.505l3.88 3.78-.917 5.34a.297.297 0 00.43.312l4.795-2.52 4.794 2.52a.296.296 0 00.43-.313l-.916-5.338L16.464 6.4c.08-.08.11-.197.075-.304z"
                  fill="#EF9546"
                  fill-rule="nonzero"
                />
              </svg>
              <svg
                class="icon"
                width="17"
                height="16"
                xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"
              >
                <path
                  d="M16.539 6.097a.297.297 0 00-.24-.202l-5.36-.779L8.542.26a.296.296 0 00-.53 0L5.613 5.117l-5.36.779a.297.297 0 00-.165.505l3.88 3.78-.917 5.34a.297.297 0 00.43.312l4.795-2.52 4.794 2.52a.296.296 0 00.43-.313l-.916-5.338L16.464 6.4c.08-.08.11-.197.075-.304z"
                  fill="#EF9546"
                  fill-rule="nonzero"
                />
              </svg>
            </span>
            Rated 5 Stars in Report Guru
          </p>
          <p class="rating rating--best">
            <span class="icons">
              <svg
                class="icon"
                width="17"
                height="16"
                xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"
              >
                <path
                  d="M16.539 6.097a.297.297 0 00-.24-.202l-5.36-.779L8.542.26a.296.296 0 00-.53 0L5.613 5.117l-5.36.779a.297.297 0 00-.165.505l3.88 3.78-.917 5.34a.297.297 0 00.43.312l4.795-2.52 4.794 2.52a.296.296 0 00.43-.313l-.916-5.338L16.464 6.4c.08-.08.11-.197.075-.304z"
                  fill="#EF9546"
                  fill-rule="nonzero"
                />
              </svg>
              <svg
                class="icon"
                width="17"
                height="16"
                xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"
              >
                <path
                  d="M16.539 6.097a.297.297 0 00-.24-.202l-5.36-.779L8.542.26a.296.296 0 00-.53 0L5.613 5.117l-5.36.779a.297.297 0 00-.165.505l3.88 3.78-.917 5.34a.297.297 0 00.43.312l4.795-2.52 4.794 2.52a.296.296 0 00.43-.313l-.916-5.338L16.464 6.4c.08-.08.11-.197.075-.304z"
                  fill="#EF9546"
                  fill-rule="nonzero"
                />
              </svg>
              <svg
                class="icon"
                width="17"
                height="16"
                xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"
              >
                <path
                  d="M16.539 6.097a.297.297 0 00-.24-.202l-5.36-.779L8.542.26a.296.296 0 00-.53 0L5.613 5.117l-5.36.779a.297.297 0 00-.165.505l3.88 3.78-.917 5.34a.297.297 0 00.43.312l4.795-2.52 4.794 2.52a.296.296 0 00.43-.313l-.916-5.338L16.464 6.4c.08-.08.11-.197.075-.304z"
                  fill="#EF9546"
                  fill-rule="nonzero"
                />
              </svg>
              <svg
                class="icon"
                width="17"
                height="16"
                xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"
              >
                <path
                  d="M16.539 6.097a.297.297 0 00-.24-.202l-5.36-.779L8.542.26a.296.296 0 00-.53 0L5.613 5.117l-5.36.779a.297.297 0 00-.165.505l3.88 3.78-.917 5.34a.297.297 0 00.43.312l4.795-2.52 4.794 2.52a.296.296 0 00.43-.313l-.916-5.338L16.464 6.4c.08-.08.11-.197.075-.304z"
                  fill="#EF9546"
                  fill-rule="nonzero"
                />
              </svg>
              <svg
                class="icon"
                width="17"
                height="16"
                xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"
              >
                <path
                  d="M16.539 6.097a.297.297 0 00-.24-.202l-5.36-.779L8.542.26a.296.296 0 00-.53 0L5.613 5.117l-5.36.779a.297.297 0 00-.165.505l3.88 3.78-.917 5.34a.297.297 0 00.43.312l4.795-2.52 4.794 2.52a.296.296 0 00.43-.313l-.916-5.338L16.464 6.4c.08-.08.11-.197.075-.304z"
                  fill="#EF9546"
                  fill-rule="nonzero"
                />
              </svg>
            </span>
            Rated 5 Stars in BestTech
          </p>
        </div>
        <div class="testimonials">
          <figure class="testimonial testimonial-colton">
            <div class="user-details">
              <img
                src="images/image-colton.jpg"
                class="testimonial-img"
                alt="Image of User"
              />
              <div class="user-content">
                <p class="user-name">Colton Smith</p>
                <p class="user-verified">Verified Buyer</p>
              </div>
            </div>
            <blockquote>
              "We needed the same printed design as the one we had ordered a
              week prior. Not only did they find the original order, but we also
              received it in time. Excellent!"
            </blockquote>
          </figure>
          <figure class="testimonial testimonial-irene">
            <div class="user-details">
              <img
                src="images/image-irene.jpg"
                class="testimonial-img"
                alt="Image of User"
              />
              <div class="user-content">
                <p class="user-name">Irene Roberts</p>
                <p class="user-verified">Verified Buyer</p>
              </div>
            </div>
            <blockquote>
              "Customer service is always excellent and very quick turn around.
              Completely delighted with the simplicity of the purchase and the
              speed of delivery."
            </blockquote>
          </figure>
          <figure class="testimonial testimonial-anne">
            <div class="user-details">
              <img
                src="images/image-anne.jpg"
                class="testimonial-img"
                alt="Image of User"
              />
              <div class="user-content">
                <p class="user-name">Anne Wallace</p>
                <p class="user-verified">Verified Buyer</p>
              </div>
            </div>
            <blockquote>
              "Put an order with this company and can only praise them for the
              very high standard. Will definitely use them again and recommend
              them to everyone!"
            </blockquote>
          </figure>
        </div>
      </section>
    </main>
  </body>
</html>
```

I changed translate x units to % and when the width goes below 376px, the elements don't translate at all. It should solve the problem